# Circuits checking with "AND", "OR", "NOT gates only

Tags: logic

I have this last question for an assignment and I've been stuck on it for hours...

Construct a machine that takes three inputs a, b, and c and has the
following output:
http://puu.sh/zBqZF/39ab9180ad.png
You may only use (two input) AND and OR gates and (one input) NOT gates,
or a subset thereof.
Use as few gates as possible. Remember that you must find one machine
that gives all of these outputs.

I have used this website: https://nrich.maths.org/5974/index to try and find a solution. I have tried atleast 50 combinations and I have no idea how to get it. There must be an easier way to do this instead of testing every possible solution. I just can't find it and I'm really frustrated, may I have some help please and thank you!

Comment: By hand is NOT the way. Karnaugh maps are the common way to produce minimized boolean expressions by hand, e.g.,
http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/minimisation/karnaugh.html

Comment: Fairly easy to do with 5 gates (and I'm not promising this is minimal), 3 ANDs, 2 ORs.

Comment: And how would you construct it with 3 ANDs 2 ORs? http://puu.sh/zBrD9/d9d72a34ee.jpg

Comment: ((a AND b) OR (a AND c)) OR (b AND c). Four gates is also possible in a fairly straightforward update from this,

Comment: http://puu.sh/zBrRr/329e00945a.jpg i got up to here and now im stuck, could you use this website https://nrich.maths.org/5974/index  to construct one if you could please?

Comment: Look more carefully at my brackets ()

Comment: Bah. Write a little program to search through all expressions and produce the smallest one. I wrote one between the time I saw the question and now that produces the result given in the answers. Why use brains when you've got a machine that can do a billion operations per second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally problems such as these are approached through [k-maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). We start by assembling the basic grid:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\frac{a,b}{c} & \text{00} & \text{01} & \text{11} & \text{10}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$

In this case, the top row indicates the truth values of $a$ and $b$, and the left column indicates the truth values of $c$. The rest of the table indicates the output given the specified truth values. From there, we must group together the 1's in the array such that they're the largest groupings as possible, and each grouping's number of elements (order) is a power of two.

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\frac{a,b}{c} & \text{00} & \text{01} & \text{11} & \text{10}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & 0\\
1 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{silver}{1} & \color{green}{1}\\
\end{array}
$$

The groupings here are the blue-silver, red-silver, and green-silver clusters. With that in mind, we can now construct our logic gates, by examining the clusters.

The blue-silver grouping is true when $A$ and $B$ are true, and true regardless of the value of $C$. Hence, we have out first cluster- $A \land B$. The second, red-silver clustering is true when $C$ and $B$ are true, regardless of the value of $A$. Hence, it is $B \land C$. By the same process, the green-silver cluster is $A \land C$. Together, we have our logic gate setup: $(A \land B)\lor(A\land C)\lor(B\land C)$.

EDIT: As the answer below helpfully points out, we can then use the distributive law: $(A \land (B \lor C))\lor(B\land C)$.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, the output is 1 exactly when at least two of the inputs are 1.   That is, $$(a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge c).$$  We can save a gate using the distributive law:

$$(a \wedge (b \vee  c)) \vee (b \wedge c).$$